# How do I share files between two computers connected to a router?

Tags: 10.04, networking, file-sharing

I have a desktop and a laptop both connected by cables to a router.

I thought the computers were supposed to show up in Nautilus in the Network folder. That way I could then easily share files between them. They do not.

Comment: What are you using to share? You can use samba, nfs, ssh (sshfs). You may simply need to add entries to `/etc/hosts` and/or entries to fstab, but it sort of depends on what protocol you are using.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I did not know what to use. I just followed Huckle's answer just now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnome 2 provides an easy way to share filesystems using `sshfs`. Essentially all that is needed is the OpenSSH server on the computer hosting the files (or both for two-way sharing). I'm not at a ubuntu machine right now because I'm at school, but if I remember correctly it should be as simple as going to *Places → Connect…* then selecting `ssh` and filling in the host's IP address.

For example, with host A at 10.0.0.1 and host B at 10.0.0.2 with the user `user` on both machines:

(execute on both machines)

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
ifconfig
```

#### Before 16.10

Then *Places → Connect…* fill in `user` for username, you password for the password and the IP address of the other computer (from `ifconfig` above).

#### After 16.10

On the left side of Nautilus, click on *+ Other Locations*. Then in the input field at the bottom (which reads *Enter server address…*) input `sftp://ip-address` - replacing ip-address with the address from `ifconfig`. In the prompt you will then supply the user and password for the computer you are connecting to.